# Does BeautifulSoup support custom html tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, download, youtube, html-parser

I was trying to build a youtube-playlist-downloader, which includes scraping the webpage of the playlist to get hrefs of the videos, using BeautifulSoup. After inspecting a youtube playlist webpage, I found that the video information is a child to `ytd-playlist-video-renderer` tags. So, I tried to run the following python script

```
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    hrefs = list()
    tags = soup('ytd-playlist-video-renderer')
    count = len(tags)
    print(count)
```

I expected it to print the number of videos in the playlist but it prints 0 every time. Is there are way around?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should use one of the `find` methods.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<custom_tag>text</custom_tag>', 'html.parser')

print(soup.findAll('custom_tag'))
print(len(soup.findAll('custom_tag')))
```

Outputs

```
[<custom_tag>text</custom_tag>]
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
# If ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer is a tag, use this
lst = doc.getElementsByTag('ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer')
print (lst)
# If ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer is a class, use this
lst = doc.getElementsByClass('ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer')
print (lst)
```